# 2002 Nissan Sentra 1.8 - where does this go? (engine turns over but won't start after unrelated repair)

Tags: starting, nissan, wiring, sentra, diagnose

Background:

- No knowledge of cars. Car running fine, then heater and engine heat began fluctuating and overheating. Expensive diagnosis- low coolant due to leaking radiator hoses, need to replace.
- To save money (unwisely?) did the top radiator hose myself since it's in reach and had the most visible leak. Removing engine side of old hose, lots of coolant spilled out all over.
- Car started just after the repair/coolant refill- a little shaky, but it's old. 5 minutes later (after cleanup) would only turn over, not start.  Let it dry 1 day, now turns over and almost starts but never all the way. No new leaks.
- Called shop (set appt 2 wks out), they felt I must have bumped or disconnected something. Looking again, noticed this wire out of place.

Questions:

- Does anyone know where this plugs in? It tends to bend back toward the left side of the battery or back behind the headlight side, but I don't see an empty connector. Lights ok.
- This cable seems somewhat far from the hose I replaced, so it may be unrelated.  Any other ideas would be welcome! Otherwise, will let it dry some more and take to shop in 2wks if no luck.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I know this is about the connector, but wondering if you have any DTC's you might have scanned from the engine to see what's going on with the car? As far as the wire goes, can you pull the insulation back a little bit so we can see the color of the wires. This should tell us what the connector is about (if we can find a wiring schematic with colors showing :o)

Comment: Thanks, Paulster2.  Sorry, no DTCs, will see if I can get a reader.  The wires are kind of dirty in the picture (will try to post) but further down behind the wrapper appear to be one black and one aqua/red.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this diagram](https://portal-diagnostov.com/en/2020/07/22/all-wiring-diagrams-for-nissan-sentra-se-r-spec-v-2002-model/) it might be for cooling fan motor 2.

[image]

Comment: Ah, that explains it... no 2nd fan on this vehicle, so they must have tucked the wire away.  Learned something new with the diagrams -Thank you for the help!